# How to hide a div if no gRPC stream(observable) data received after X secs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, grpc, rxjs-observables

I'm working on binding stream data that is consumed from a gRPC service stream call. The stream data is sent every X millisecs from the gRPC service and i'm binding this as observable data to a div in html, like simple ngIf*.

I need to handle a case when the service is not sending any data after X secs, I should not show a div. So planning to explicitly set null to the binding variable only when there is no stream received after X seconds.

So trying to figure out the best way to do this with RxJs operators. I was looking at Interval, timer, switchMap, but not sure how to implement it correctly.

**Service.ts**

```
  @Injectable()
    export class ApiMyTestService {    
        client: GrpcMyTestServiceClient;
        public readonly testData$: Observable<TestReply.AsObject>;
  
    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
        this.client = new GrpcMyTestServiceClient(environment.apiProxyUri);
        this.testData$ = this.listCoreStream();
    }
  
   listCoreStream(): Observable <TestReply.AsObject> {
    return new Observable(obs => {      
      const req = new SomeRequest(); 
      req.setClientName("GrpcWebTestClient");
      const stream = this.client.getCoreUpdates(req); // Main gRPC Server stream Api call 
      
      stream.on('status', (status: Status) => {
        console.log('ApiService.getStream.status', status);
      });
      
      stream.on('data', (message: any) => {
        // gRPC Api call returns stream data here. Every X millisec service sends stream data.
        console.log('ApiService.getStream.data', message.toObject());
        obs.next(message.toObject() as TestReply.AsObject);
      });
      
      stream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('ApiService.getStream.end');
        obs.complete();        
      });     
    });
  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {   
   public testReply?: TestReply.AsObject;   
   private _subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private readonly _MyTestService: ApiMyTestService) {     
      this._subscription = new Subscription();
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {    
        this._subscription = this._MyTestService.testData$.subscribe((data) => {           
           //testReply will be binded to a div, so hide div if null data
           // how to set to null when the service didn't stream any data after X seconds
           this.testReply = data;
            
        });
}
```

**Html:**

```
//show this div only when we have stream data. Hide it when no data is binded for X secs!
<div *ngIf=(testReply)>
    html elements that uses testReply
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an observable that emits the values from your service, but will also emit `undefined` after x number of seconds:

```js
public testReply$ = this._MyTestService.testData$.pipe(
    switchMap(data => merge(
        of(data), 
        timer(5000).pipe(mapTo(undefined))
    ))
);
```

Here's how it works:

- [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) creates a singe observable from multiple sources, which will emit when any source emits.  In this case the sources are:

  - The emitted value from the service (`data`). [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) is used to create an observable from our plain value
  - An observable that will emit `undefined` after 5000ms.  `timer()` will emit the number `0` after the specified time, so we use [`mapTo`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mapto) to emit `undefined` instead.
- [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) subscribes to this "inner observable" for us and emit it's emissions.  It will also replace the inner observable with a new one each time it receives an emission.  Therefore, the `timer()` will only emit if `switchMap` doesn't receive the next emission within 5000ms.

Now, you just use `testReply$`:

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {    
    this._subscription = this.testReply$.subscribe(
        data => this.testReply = data
    );
}
```

---

To simplify things a bit, you can leverayge the `AsyncPipe` in your template, and not need to worry about subscriptions:

```html
<div *ngIf="testReply$ | async as testReply">
    <p> {{ testReply }} </p>
</div>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {

  public testReply$: Observable<TestReply.AsObject> = this._MyTestService.testData$.pipe(
    switchMap(data => merge(
      of(data), 
      timer(5000).pipe(mapTo(undefined))
    ))
  );

  constructor(private readonly _MyTestService: ApiMyTestService) { }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks @BizzyBob for explanation and clarifying with additional details.